# Python: How can I replace full-width characters with half-width characters?

Tags: python, unicode, translation

If this was PHP, I would probably do something like this:

```
function no_more_half_widths($string){
  $foo = array('１','２','３','４','５','６','７','８','９','１０')
  $bar = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')
  return str_replace($foo, $bar, $string)
}
```

I have tried the .translate function in python and it indicates that the arrays are not of the same size.  I assume this is due to the fact that the individual characters are encoded in utf-8.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The built-in `unicodedata` module can do it:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> foo = u'１２３４５６７８９０'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', foo)
u'1234567890'
```

The “NFKC” stands for “[Normalization Form](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) KC [Compatibility Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition]”, and replaces full-width characters by half-width ones, which are [Unicode equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Note that it also normalizes all sorts of other things at the same time, like separate accent marks and Roman numeral symbols.

Comment: This is very slick, but has side effects (as you note), and inflexible: it only goes one way (full-width to half-width). Still, if that’s acceptable, this is nice!

Comment: Thanks.  It helped me find the JVM equivalent: `Normalizer.normalize(ch.toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFKC ).get(0)`.  It works for my personal project :-)

Answer (score 11):

In Python3, you can use the following snippet. It makes a map between all ASCII characters and corresponding fullwidth characters. Best of all, this doesn't need you to hard code the ascii sequence, which is error prone.

```
 FULL2HALF = dict((i + 0xFEE0, i) for i in range(0x21, 0x7F))
 FULL2HALF[0x3000] = 0x20
      
 def halfen(s):
     '''
     Convert full-width characters to ASCII counterpart
     '''
     return str(s).translate(FULL2HALF)
```

Also, with same logic, you can convert halfwidth characters to fullwidth, with the following code:

```
 HALF2FULL = dict((i, i + 0xFEE0) for i in range(0x21, 0x7F))
 HALF2FULL[0x20] = 0x3000
      
 def fullen(s):
     '''
     Convert all ASCII characters to the full-width counterpart.
     '''
     return str(s).translate(HALF2FULL)
```

Note: These two snippets only consider ASCII characters, and does not convert any japanese/korean fullwidth characters.

For completeness, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms#In_Unicode):

> Range `U+FF01–FF5E` reproduces the characters of ASCII 21 to 7E as
> fullwidth forms, that is, a fixed width form used in CJK
> computing. This is useful for typesetting Latin characters in a CJK
> environment. `U+FF00` does not correspond to a fullwidth ASCII 20
> (space character), since that role is already fulfilled by `U+3000`
> "ideographic space."
>
> Range `U+FF65–FFDC` encodes halfwidth forms of Katakana and Hangul
> characters.
>
> Range `U+FFE0–FFEE` includes fullwidth and halfwidth symbols.

A python2 solution can be found at [gist/jcayzac](https://gist.github.com/jcayzac/1485005).

Comment: Thanks for your perfect solution! it really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a built-in function to do multiple replacements in one pass, so you'll have to do it yourself.

One way to do it:

```
>>> src = (u'１',u'２',u'３',u'４',u'５',u'６',u'７',u'８',u'９',u'１０')
>>> dst = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
>>> string = u'a１２３'
>>> for i, j in zip(src, dst):
...     string = string.replace(i, j)
... 
>>> string
u'a123'
```

Or using a dictionary:

```
>>> trans = {u'１': '1', u'２': '2', u'３': '3', u'４': '4', u'５': '5', u'６': '6', u'７': '7', u'８': '8', u'９': '9', u'０': '0'}
>>> string = u'a１２３'
>>> for i, j in trans.iteritems():
...     string = string.replace(i, j)
...     
>>> string
u'a123'
```

Or finally, using regex (and this might actually be the fastest):

```
>>> import re
>>> trans = {u'１': '1', u'２': '2', u'３': '3', u'４': '4', u'５': '5', u'６': '6', u'７': '7', u'８': '8', u'９': '9', u'０': '0'}
>>> lookup = re.compile(u'|'.join(trans.keys()), re.UNICODE)
>>> string = u'a１２３'
>>> lookup.sub(lambda x: trans[x.group()], string)
u'a123'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `unicode.translate` method:

```
>>> table = dict(zip(map(ord,u'０１２３４５６７８９'),map(ord,u'0123456789')))
>>> print u'１２３'.translate(table)
123
```

It requires a mapping of code points as *numbers*, not characters. Also, using `u'unicode literals'` leaves the values unencoded.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know `unicode` had a `translate()` method different from pure `str`, though in retrospect it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

Regex approach

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(u"[\uff10-\uff19]",lambda x:chr(ord(x.group(0))-0xfee0),u"４５６")
u'456'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, cleanest is to use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
FULLWIDTH_TO_HALFWIDTH = str.maketrans('１２３４５６７８９０',
                                       '1234567890')
def fullwidth_to_halfwidth(s):
    return s.translate(FULLWIDTH_TO_HALFWIDTH)
```

In Python 2, str.maketrans is instead [string.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and doesn’t work with Unicode characters, so you need to make a dictionary, as Josh Lee notes above.