# Convert ASCII chars to Unicode FULLWIDTH latin letters in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode

Can you easily convert between ASCII characters and their Asian full-width Unicode wide characters?
Like:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

to

```
０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝＝〉？＠［\\］＾＿‘｛｜｝～
```

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422177/python-how-can-i-replace-full-width-characters-with-half-width-characters

Comment: @Mark Don't call something stupid unless you understand it. It's used in Asian writing to embed latin scripts among "double wide" asian characters because it's more natural to read, especially in vertical text and grid-style blocks. E.g.: これはＰｙｔｈｏｎの質問だぞ。

Comment: @deceze, thanks for explaining that, perhaps I was a bit rash in calling it stupid. It does seem like there should be better ways of handling that problem though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those "wide" characters are named `FULLWIDTH LATIN LETTER`: http://www.unicodemap.org/range/87/Halfwidth%20and%20Fullwidth%20Forms/

They have range 0xFF00 - -0xFFEF. You can make look-up table or just add 0xFEE0 to ASCII code.

Comment: Nice. Bit of a noob here, how to get the ASCII char's hex value, add that to the 0xff20 hex value, and convert the hex back to string?

Comment: simply `chr(0xFF20 + ord(asciichar))` :)

Comment: Are you sure? `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

Comment: oops. You use python2? Then `unichr(0xFF20 + ord(asciichar))`

Comment: Something still seems wrong, but it could be an api specific question. Can I just get the data as string object, not unicode, and work from that? :)

Comment: String objects in python 2.x hold characters in ASCII (8-bit). So you can't hold special UNICODE characters (like described above) in them. You need unicode strings for it. If your project is new and does not use some specific python 2.x modules, I suggest to switch to a python 3.x. Among other changes, it holds string objects in unicode chars (but you'll still have problem with printing them to windows console, since it does no support unicode)

Comment: I think you can have something like "\xFF20\xFF20\xFF20". Anyway, I'm trying to render the characters with my font file and it fails to recognise the character codes. However it works if I just pass it the unicode strings in the Python script.

Comment: I think my problem is in joining the characters, I do `u''.join(mycharlist)`. EDIT, maybe not.

Comment: Hmm, I think `u''.join(mycharlist)` should work fine. Are all elements of `mycharlist` have type `unicode` ? It can fail, if there are mixed elements - `str` and `unicode`. Can you show, what error it produces?

Comment: It's an API specific error. But in short, the font file says it doesn't have such character codes. Again it doesn't complain if I feed it the string from the Python script file. Yes, all elements of mycharlist are unicode. have you tried it yourself? If it works for you, then probably I'm doing something very wrong here.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I made error, calculating offset. We should use `unichr(0xFEE0 + ord(asciichar))`. Now it works fine. I fixed answer.

Answer (score 10):

The range of fullwidth ASCII replacements starts at U+FF01, not U+FF00. U+FF00 is (strangely) not defined. To get a fullwidth SPACE, you need to use U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE. Don't rely on typing what *appears* to be what you want followed by visual inspection of characters to check your mapping -- `unicodedata.name` is your friend. This code:

```
# coding: utf-8
from unicodedata import name as ucname

# OP
normal = u"""0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"""
wide = u"""０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［\\］＾＿‘｛｜｝～"""
# above after editing (had = twice)
widemapOP = dict((ord(x[0]), x[1]) for x in zip(normal, wide))

# Ingacio V
normal = u' 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
wide = u'　０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［\\］＾＿‘｛｜｝～'
widemapIV = dict((ord(x[0]), x[1]) for x in zip(normal, wide))

# JM
widemapJM = dict((i, i + 0xFF00 - 0x20) for i in xrange(0x21, 0x7F))
widemapJM[0x20] = 0x3000 # IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

maps = {'OP': widemapOP, 'IV': widemapIV, 'JM': widemapJM}.items()

for i in xrange(0x20, 0x7F):
    a = unichr(i)
    na = ucname(a, '?')
    for tag, widemap in maps:
        w = a.translate(widemap)
        nw = ucname(w, '?')
        if nw != "FULLWIDTH " + na:
            print "%s: %04X %s => %04X %s" % (tag, i, na, ord(w), nw)
```

when run shows what you have *really* got: some missing mappings and some idiosyncratic mappings:

```
JM: 0020 SPACE => 3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
IV: 0020 SPACE => 3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
OP: 0020 SPACE => 0020 SPACE
IV: 0022 QUOTATION MARK => 309B KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK
OP: 0022 QUOTATION MARK => 309B KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK
IV: 0027 APOSTROPHE => 0027 APOSTROPHE
OP: 0027 APOSTROPHE => 0027 APOSTROPHE
IV: 002C COMMA => 3001 IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA
OP: 002C COMMA => 3001 IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA
IV: 002D HYPHEN-MINUS => 30FC KATAKANA-HIRAGANA PROLONGED SOUND MARK
OP: 002D HYPHEN-MINUS => 30FC KATAKANA-HIRAGANA PROLONGED SOUND MARK
IV: 002E FULL STOP => 3002 IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP
OP: 002E FULL STOP => 3002 IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP
IV: 003C LESS-THAN SIGN => 3008 LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
OP: 003C LESS-THAN SIGN => 3008 LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
IV: 003E GREATER-THAN SIGN => 3009 RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
OP: 003E GREATER-THAN SIGN => 3009 RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
IV: 005C REVERSE SOLIDUS => 005C REVERSE SOLIDUS
OP: 005C REVERSE SOLIDUS => 005C REVERSE SOLIDUS
IV: 0060 GRAVE ACCENT => 2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
OP: 0060 GRAVE ACCENT => 2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
>>> normal = u' 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> wide = u'　０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［\\］＾＿‘｛｜｝～'
>>> widemap = dict((ord(x[0]), x[1]) for x in zip(normal, wide))
>>> print u'Hello, world!'.translate(widemap)
Ｈｅｌｌｏ、　ｗｏｒｌｄ！
```

Comment: +1 clever! But I keep getting `Ｇｅｌｌｏ＋　 ｏｒｌｄＺ` as a translating of `Hello world!`

Comment: @julio.alegria: Then you have a missing or extra character somewhere.

Comment: Well that's an option, hehe. What if I'm not sure my two strings are correct or complete?

Comment: By zipping the strings, printing the characters side by side, and making sure they match.

Comment: I'm guessing what he's saying is that your solution just works  with a static set of characters

Comment: The set of wide characters *is* static. At least until the Unicode consortium decides to add some more.

Comment: -1 Solution requires laborious typing and is thus brittle as evidenced by above comments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; in Python 3, cleanest is to use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
HALFWIDTH_TO_FULLWIDTH = str.maketrans(
    '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~',
    '０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［］＾＿‘｛｜｝～')

def halfwidth_to_fullwidth(s):
    return s.translate(HALFWIDTH_TO_FULLWIDTH)
```

In Python 2, str.maketrans is instead [string.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and doesn’t work with Unicode characters, so you need to make a dictionary, as Ignacio Vazquez notes above.

Comment: This answer seems better to me than the others. It's a cleaner and shorter solution and works exactly as it should. I'm assuming it wasn't available back in 2011 though.

Comment: you may want to add space (' ') and ideographic space ('　') to the lists for completeness.

Comment: Fair point @Stef – I was just answering the original question, and the list is incomplete. See the answer by Heizi for an automated way and complete list.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a way to convert **any** FULLWIDTH, HALFWIDTH or IDEOGRAPHIC unicode
character to their 'normal' equivalent **if** they have one.

I ended up writing my own solution because I wanted one that doesn't rely on a manually input translation string, which can only result in missing/incorrect mappings as demonstrated by John Machin answer. Here's the code if it's of use to anyone :

```
import unicodedata 
unicode_range = (0, 0x10ffff)

# create a dict of where the values are unicode characters
# and the keys are the character names, if they have one.
chars = {}
for uc_point in range(unicode_range[0], unicode_range[1]+1):
    char = chr(uc_point)
    try:
        name = unicodedata.name(char)
        chars[name] = char
    except ValueError: #chars with no name such as control characters
        pass

def normal(name):
    # 'IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA' -> 'COMMA'
    # 'HALFWIDTH IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA' -> 'COMMA'
    # 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A' -> None 
    # so we want to look foor these at the start of character names:
    starts = ['HALFWIDTH IDEOGRAPHIC','IDEOGRAPHIC','FULLWIDTH','HALFWIDTH']
    l = [name[len(start)+1:] for start in starts if name.startswith(start)]
    if l:
        return l[0]
    else:
        return None

# who doesn't love a bit of dict comprehension for the finish:
mapping = {chars[name]: chars[normal(name)] for name in chars if normal(name) in chars}
```

This gets us a neat mapping that can then be used with str.maketrans() and str.translate() as demonstrated in Nils von Barth's answer:

```
>>> ''.join(mapping.keys())
'\u3000、。！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～｟｠｡｢｣､･ｦｧｨｩｪｫｬｭｮｯｰｱｲｳｴｵｶｷｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃﾄﾅﾆﾇﾈﾉﾊﾋﾌﾍﾎﾏﾐﾑﾒﾓﾔﾕﾖﾗﾘﾙﾚﾛﾜﾝﾠﾡﾢﾣﾤﾥﾦﾧﾨﾩﾪﾫﾬﾭﾮﾯﾰﾱﾲﾳﾴﾵﾶﾷﾸﾹﾺﾻﾼﾽﾾￂￃￄￅￆￇￊￋￌￍￎￏￒￓￔￕￖￗￚￛￜ￠￡￢￣￤￥￦￩￪￫￬￭￮'
```

and

```
>>> ''.join(mapping.values())
' ,.!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⦅⦆.「」,・ヲァィゥェォャュョッーアイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワンㅤㄱㄲㄳㄴㄵㄶㄷㄸㄹㄺㄻㄼㄽㄾㄿㅀㅁㅂㅃㅄㅅㅆㅇㅈㅉㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎㅏㅐㅑㅒㅓㅔㅕㅖㅗㅘㅙㅚㅛㅜㅝㅞㅟㅠㅡㅢㅣ¢£¬¯¦¥₩←↑→↓■○'
```

This solution is also future-proof as it relies on the stdlib module unicodedata which gets updated often with the latest Unicode database.

Answer (score 0):

This goes one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# uniwide
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

while (<>) {    
    s/\s/\x{A0}\x{A0}/g if tr
      <!"#$%&´()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¢£>
      <！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～￠￡>;;    
} continue {
      print;   
} 

close(STDOUT) || die "can't close stdout: $!";
```

And this goes the other:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# uninarrow
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

while (<>) {     
    s/  / /g if tr
      <！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～￠￡>
      <!"#$%&´()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¢£>    
} continue {
      print;    
} 

close(STDOUT) || die "can't close stdout: $!";
```

Comment: what programming language is this?

Comment: For some reason the `python` tag really is too small on this one... :o)

Answer (score -3):

UTF-8 Unicode codes for ASCII are exactly the same. For UTF-16 add a zero before/after (LE/BE)

Or in python `mystr.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think in unicode you have normal "width" ascii characters which indeed are the same, but there are wider versions (like above) which have another code.

Comment: `0123456789a` != `０１２３４５６７８９ａ`.

Comment: @glglgl the question was improperly put, I had to edit it to clean it.