# How to convert Unicode contained inside an HTML link?

Tags: python, unicode

I've got the following HTML code :

```
<a href="http://&#65346;&#65345;&#65348;&#65294;&#65347;&#65359;&#65357;">Bad URL</a>
```

This is a string `\uff42\uff41\uff44\uff0e\uff43\uff4f\uff4d` which both
Chrome and Firefox think [http://ｂａｄ．ｃｏｍ](http://%EF%BD%82%EF%BD%81%EF%BD%84%EF%BC%8E%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%8D) is the same as http://bad.com.

I need to compare the collected URLs with a list of whitelisted URLs.

How do I convert [http://ｂａｄ．ｃｏｍ](http://%EF%BD%82%EF%BD%81%EF%BD%84%EF%BC%8E%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%8D) to http://bad.com using Python? Do the browsers replace "confusible" characters?

Alternatively is it possible to compare two URLs?

Comment: I got -1 again. Is there anything I can do to improve the question?

Comment: Also this answer is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422177/python-how-can-i-replace-full-width-characters-with-half-width-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html):

```
import unicodedata

link = 'http://ｂａｄ．ｃｏｍ'
normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', link)
```

What is `'NFKC'` you can find in [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

Comment: I have burnt two hours with this one. I did not want to go byte by byte. Thanks!