# Panda: can't merge, maybe encoding issues

Tags: pandas, encoding, merge, fonts

I am merging two tables in panda. One DF comes from the JP Census (API query) and the other DF is an Excel import. I can't merge the two tables, maybe because of encoding issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9mWm.png)

For instance on this picture, the NO should match to NO, but it doesn't. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have some unicode text that is using these characters: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff2e/index.htm  If you really want to "normalize" or "munge" your data to put it into regular ascii + latin script see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422177/python-how-can-i-replace-full-width-characters-with-half-width-characters

Comment: As a tip: `import unicodedata; unicodedata.name("Ｎ") ; # 'FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N'`