# Change from Japanese font style to English font style in Python

Tags: python, database, fonts, cjk

So i have trouble with Japanese font like "９３９－２３６７", what i read in Japanese database.
It's different with normal font in my PC like 0123456789.
So how can i convert Japanese font to English font by Python?

Comment: Those are full-width characters. You can convert them with `unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '９３９－２３６７')`. Please take a look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422177/python-how-can-i-replace-full-width-characters-with-half-width-characters